# How to replace a JSON String with Java?

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch

In my JSON Array inside of its file, it has an array set that goes as follows:

```
{
"user_interface_fields" : {
"tip_identifier" : {
"uuid": "12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789112"
}
"insert_time" : "2001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
}
```

And now I got this file written in java

```
@Test
public void testExampleMessageToJson() throws Throwable {
log.info("\n\nTesting persist service [message to json]?\n");

//Setup
String rawJson = TestUtils.getResourceMessage("examples/life.json");
String tip_identifier_uuid = "12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789112";

log.info("Raw Json:\n():", rawJson); 
assertTrue(StringUtils.isNotBlank(rawJson));

//Test
JSONObject foundObj = persistService.messageToJson(rawJson); 

//Verify
String tip_identifier_time = foundObj.getString("insert_time");
String new_time = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
foundObj.put(new_time, foundObj).getString("insert_time");\
assertNotNull(foundObj);

String new_uuid = foundObj.getJSONObject("user_interface_fields").getJSONObject("tip_identifier").getString("uuid");
assertEquals(tip_identifier_uuid , new_uuid); 
assertEquals(tip_identifier_time, new_time);
log.info("\n\nTesting persist service [message to json] COMPLETE!\n");
}
```

My goal is to have life.json's time to be nearly identical to our current time (so like if it's 11/11/21 01:30:21.22, insert_time's data should be around 01:30:21.2234 or whatever and at any time i or any other person runs the code it should be a near match..)

But in my failure trace it tells me:
`org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<202[0-02-19'T'00:00:]00> but was:<202[1-11T17:46:46+00]00>`

I'm thinking that the logging is messed up because expected should be nearly matched as the current time (as stated in my goal). Since messagetoJson gets the current time and inserts it, when my test pulls out the insert_time it should be a couple of milliseconds behind and so I need to validate that it's within a second or ~1000 milliseconds.

But I don't know what the heck I should do or where I should go from here in order to fix that.

Comment: Well, your code compares the String of what looks like to be two different formatting schemes. Have you considered storing the time as something like milliseconds since epoch? See here https://www.epochconverter.com/. You can get the time since epoch with "new Date.getTime()" and then you can compare this number with a certain range, like 1000 like you specified.

Comment: @PieterSvenson is that why im getting that failure trace? because of the formatting schemes not being compatible?

Comment: Yeah, if the line that is giving the error is the second to last one, then it's comparing two strings. "<202[0-02-19'T'00:00:]00>" is not the same as "<202[1-11T17:46:46+00]00>", and making these strings identical is a tedious endeavor. I would just compare the epoch time.

Comment: Hi, you've posted similar question 2 days ago, what's the difference? [How Do I overwrite data from a JSONObject using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69903850/how-do-i-overwrite-data-from-a-jsonobject-using-java)